# Can't translate pager labels in View

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have a view to show post teasers. Inside the view I go to 'translate view' and change the values for tags, date, etc. accordingly. Everything translates fine except the text for 'first' and 'last', which stay in the default language (Spanish) no matter if I switch to English (they stay as 'primera' and 'última'). Every other label works so I'm at a loss here.

Can someone point out if I'm doing something wrong? Maybe I should enable another module but I don't think so. Every other node, block, page and menu works fine in both languages. The problem is just with the mentioned labels.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be solved by drupal community:
https://drupal.org/node/2112281#comment-7971057

Answer (score 1):

These are ui translations, strings inside a t('');

You must install locale module and go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate.

Then add the translations for the pager

Regards.

Comment: I have locale installed.  And the translations are there (in admin/config/regional/translate/translate) and are correct.  They're just not changing with the language and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the views3 version. There is some real translatable support via [i18nviews](https://drupal.org/project/i18nviews).

Views provides some kind of pluggable translation system now.

Comment: I'm already using both Views3 and i18nviews.  That's how I got everything else translated, except for those stubborn pager labels.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just ran into this known issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1794912
The problem occurs in cases where the original language of the view isn't english. Try to do a workaround by implementing `hook_views_pre_render` in a custom module as explained in [comment#10](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1794912#comment-9476883).